# What are the possible ways to Monitor the state of Log Reader agent job?

Tags: sql-server, monitoring

Monitoring of Log reader agent job in a way that whenever it is not running/executing it would triggers an alert, or is there any way of registering the state of log reader agent job as an event in the logs so that the data can be polled to any monitoring platform and a alert can be created ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/agents/use-alerts-for-replication-agent-events?view=sql-server-ver16